# How to do the Assert phase of a private method whose return type is Void?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, private-methods

I have a class with a private method

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private void SomeMethod(PrimaryAllocationDP packet)
    {
        ........................
        some code
        ........................
        packet.AllocatedAgency = AgencyAllocated;
    }
}
```

Now by using MSUnit Testing framework, I have written so far

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAllocatedAgency()
{ 

    var packet = new Fixture().Create<PrimaryAllocationDP>(); //used AutoFixture here

    PrivateObject accessor = new PrivateObject(new MyClass());     

    accessor.Invoke("SomeMethod", packet); //Act

    // what will be the Assert? Since it is void
}
```

What will be the Assert? Since it is void, how can I write the assert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well given that in the example the method under test is making a change to its argument/dependency you could assert that the desired result of calling the function is that the packet's `AllocatedAgency` property is in fact not `null`

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestAllocatedAgency() { 
    //Arrange
    var packet = new Fixture().Create<PrimaryAllocationDP>(); //used AutoFixture here
    var sut = new MyClass();
    var accessor = new PrivateObject(sut);     

    //Act
    accessor.Invoke("SomeMethod", packet);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(packet.AllocatedAgency);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to change `PrimaryAllocationDP` you can also add a new interface `IPrimaryAllocationDP` and test the property setting. In my test I am assuming `AllocatedAgency` is of type object and I am using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart). But maybe you can also use `AutoFixture` for mocking? To make it more clear I set `AgencyAllocated` directly in `MyClass`

```
[TestFixture]
public class DependencyInjection
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAllocatedAgency()
    {
        var packet = new Mock<IPrimaryAllocationDP>();

        PrivateObject accessor = new PrivateObject(new MyClass());

        accessor.Invoke("SomeMethod", packet.Object); //Act

        packet.VerifySet(p => p.AllocatedAgency = 42);
    }
}

public interface IPrimaryAllocationDP
{
    //object or any other type
    object AllocatedAgency { set; }
}

public class PrimaryAllocationDP : IPrimaryAllocationDP
{
    public object AllocatedAgency { set; private get; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly object AgencyAllocated = 42;

    private void SomeMethod(IPrimaryAllocationDP packet)
    {
        //........................
        //some code
        //........................
        packet.AllocatedAgency = AgencyAllocated;
    }
}
```